# python re codecs ä ö, finnish language, define that is word

Tags: python, regex, codec

IS it possible to define that specific languages characters would be considered as word.
I.e. re do not accept ä,ö as word characters if i search them in following way

```
Ft=codecs.open('c:\\Python27\\Scripts\\finnish2\\textfields.txt','r','utf–8')
word=Ft.readlines()
word=smart_str(word, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='replace')
word=re.sub('[^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9]',"""\[^A-Za-z0-9]*""", word) ; print 'word=  ', word #works in skipping ö,ä,å characters
```

I would like that these character would be included to [A-Za-z]. 
How to define this?

Answer (score 4):

`[A-Za-z0-9]` will only match the characters listed here, but the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) also mention some other special constructs like:

- `\w` which stands for alphanumeric characters (namely `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` plus all unicode characters which are declared to be alphanumeric
- `\W` which stands for all nun-alphanumeric characters `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` plus unicode
- `\d` which stands for digits
- `\b` which matches word boundaries (including all rules from the unicode tables)

So, you will to (a) use this constructs instead (which are shorter and maybe easier to read), and (b) tell re that you want to "localize" those strings with the current locale by setting the UNICODE flag like:

```
re_word = re.compile(r'\w+', re.U)
```

Comment: `re.UNICODE` is locale-independent, use `re.LOCALE` to depend on the current locale.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, you appear to be slightly confused about the args for re.sub.

The first arg is the pattern. You have '[^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9]' which matches each character which is NOT in the Finnish alphabet nor a digit.

The second arg is the replacement. You have """[^A-Za-z0-9]*""" ... so each of those non-Finnish-alphanumeric characters is going to be replaced by the literal string `[^A-Za-z0-9]*`. It's reasonable to assume that this is not what you want.

1. What *do* you want to do?
2. You need to explain your third line; after your first 2 lines, `word` will be a list of `unicode` objects, which is A Good Thing. However the `encoding=` and the `errors=` indicate that the unknown (to us) smart_str() is converting your lovely unicode back to UTF-8. Processing data in UTF-8 bytes instead of Unicode characters is EVIL, unless you know what you are doing.
3. What encoding directive do you have at the top of your source file?
4. Advice: Get your data into unicode. Work on it in unicode. All your string constants should have the `u` prefix; if you consider that too much wear and tear on your typing fingers, at least put it on the non-ASCII constants e.g. `u'[^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9]'`. When you have done all the processing, encode your results for display or storage using an appropriate encoding.
5. When working with `re`, consider `\w` which will match any alphanumeric (and also the underscore) instead of listing out what is alphabetic in one language. Do use the re.UNICODE flag; docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.UNICODE).

Comment: After the first 2 lines the `word` will be a **list** of Unicode strings.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick:

```
pattern = re.compile("(?u)pattern")
```

or

```
pattern = re.compile("pattern", re.UNICODE)
```